# How does malloc know where the first available block is in embedded systems?

Tags: embedded, malloc, bare-metal

I have read that `malloc` has multiple implementations which are platform depended.

How does it work in an embedded device in bare metal programming?
Let's suppose we have an mcu with 256KB FLASH memory and 64KB RAM.

How does it know how much available RAM there is from my program?

Comment: As you have read, it depends on the implementation. Some might need a setup from the linker script, others might need an implementation of `sbrk()` or similar, and so on. Do you have a specific platform in your mind? Then read its documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For bare metal systems, you'll have a specific segment allocated in the linker script, often called `.heap`. There is no such thing as memory sharing between processes, meaning that the heap must have a fixed maximum size and therefore is pretty useless in general. `malloc` doesn't know a thing about how much RAM your program uses since there is no desktop OS in sight.

Your RAM is divided into `.stack`, `.data`, `.bss` and `.heap`, each with its own fixed maximum size. More about these segments here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/237759/6102. In a typical bare metal MCU application, most of the RAM will be reserved for `.data` and `.bss`. You will have something from 128 bytes up to several kb reserved for the stack. You will typically not have a heap at all - but if you do, it will sit there and take up a fixed amount of x kb no matter how much of it you actually use.

`malloc` in itself could be implemented in different ways indeed. Either you include a "header" together with each allocated segment, the header stating the allocated size and potentially the address of the next available free segment. Or you could implement it as a look-up table where each item is a pointer to the first element and the size.

None of this is particularly relevant, since you shouldn't be using heap allocation in embedded systems. The main reason being that [it doesn't make any sense](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/171581/6102). You don't want arbitrary behavior, you want deteministic behavior. You want to allocate x amount of memory for the worst case and if a heap was to be used it would have to be at least that large anyway, so you gain nothing but bloat from using a heap. Then comes all the usual problems with allocation overhead, fragmentation and leaks.

For bare metal/RTOS applications, do yourself a favour and delete `.heap` from your linker script, then forget that you ever heard about `malloc`. A MCU is not a PC.